# RXJS polling without recursion

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Server is processing multiple request at the same time. Call the service to check the status of each request. Service accepts list of ids and will give status of each id as following

```
{ id: number, status: number}; Status 1 is pending and 2 is complete
```

Need to poll on all the pending request ids until all requests are complete

I have a following recursive solution but need a concise RXJS solution for it

```
 poll(requestIds: Array<number>): void {
    if (requestIds.length > 0) {
        callService(requestIds).subscribe((response) => {
            const pending = response.reduce((result, request) => {
                if (request.status === 1) { result.push(request.id); }
            }, []);
            setTimeout(() => poll(pending), 5000);

        });
    }
}
```

Not mentioned in the above example is the clearTimeout and list of subscription which gets cleared when polling stops. I know that this could be acheived with repeatWhen and takeWhile

Comment: You can use the `expand` operator: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602

Comment: It will still be recursive call.

Comment: No, it will be iterative. Conceptually recursive, perhaps, but the implementation will be iterative.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution using `repeatWhen` or `takeWhen`? What do you have so far?

Comment: The blog post link in the above comment is no longer valid. The canonical link for the post is: https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an rxjs stream that achieves your recursion:

```
callService(ids).pipe(
  expand(reqs => reqs.length === 0
    ? empty()
    : callService(
        reqs.filter(req => req.status === 1).map(req => req.id)
      ).pipe(delay(1000))
  )
).subscribe();
```

Here you can see a demonstration: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aaxiru