# Subscription for switchMap not called when observable takes more time

Tags: angular, rxjs, polling

```
startPolling() {
timer(1, 5000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.gatewayService.get(this.id)),
  retry(),
  share(),
  takeUntil(this.stopPolling)
).subscribe((gateway) => {
  this.status = gateway.status;
  this.stopPollingIfImageDownloaded();
});
```

in the above code subscription doesnt work if gatewayService.get call takes more than 5 sec.
So the switchMap cancelling the prev subscription.

Any solution to this problem.

Basically i want to do polling for status and the call may take time

Comment: this post is pretty much like yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046860/rxjs-polling-without-recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use `mergeMap` or `exhaustMap`.

The difference is that:

- `mergeMap` will subscribe every 5 seconds without unsubscribing (cancelling) the previous API call. This means you could have many concurrent subscriptions.
- `exhaustMap` will not subscribe again, unless the current API call has finished, but it also will not cancel the running API call. In this case, you may need to wait up to 5 seconds after a successful response until it re-subscribes.

Comment: exhaustMap is the best option among all, It meets my requirement